# Getting rowcount for a column based on values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, T1 AND T2.

T1 with following columns: `Id, TypeofValue, Year, value`

`Typeofvalue` can have 2 values

`1` - indicates `Actual`

`2` - indicates `Target`

T2 With following column: NoOfRecordsToDisplay

I need to fetch the number of records (if existing)  for `Target` corresponding to an `Id`.

However, the catches are:

1. Sometimes Target value might not be present for a year
2. I need to get only last records for targets on the basis of NoOfRecordsToDisplay (The number of records to display comes from T2) for actual

Example1:
NoOfRecordsToDisplay =3, ID =123
The data below should return 3 as we have 3 non null values for target for last 3 years -2015, 2014,2013 in this case

```
Id  TypeofValue     Year    Value
123     1           2015    55
123     1           2014    56
123     1           2013    57
123     1           2012    58
123     2           2015    50
123     2           2014    50
123     2           2013    50
123     2           2012    50
124     1           2015    55
124     1           2014    56
124     1           2013    57
124     1           2012    58
124     2           2015    50
124     2           2014    50
124     2           2013    50
124     2           2012    50
```

Another dataset -
NoOfRecordsToDisplay =3, ID =123
The data below should return 0, as we have no  values for target for last 3 years -2015, 2014,2013

```
Id  TypeofValue     Year    Value
123     1           2015    55
123     1           2014    56
123     1           2013    57
123     1           2012    58
123     2           2012    50
124     1           2015    55
124     1           2014    56
124     1           2013    57
124     1           2012    58
124     2           2012    50
```

Comment: So are you asking about mySQL or SQL Server? Also, it's not clear what the criteria for your queries should be... can you at update your question with WHERE clauses for the examples you give?

Comment: done. Made the edits to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so if I understand correctly, you want a count of rows where the TypeOfValue = 2, and the Year is in the top *n* values where TypeOfValue = 1, for a given `Id`.

This should be:

```
DECLARE @Id int, @NoOfRecordsToDisplay int

SET @Id = 123
SET @NoOfRecordsToDisplay = 3

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable
WHERE
  TypeofValue = 2
  AND Id = @Id
  AND [Year] IN ( SELECT TOP(@NoOfRecordsToDisplay) [Year] FROM myTable
              WHERE TypeofValue = 1 AND Id = @Id
              ORDER BY [Year] DESC)
```

In practice, you would probably want to create this as a stored proc with @Id as an input parameter. @NoOfRecordsToDisplay could either be a parameter too, or selected from some other table - I'm still not 100% clear on this from your question.

Updated SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87b0c/2

**Edit:** Forgot the ORDER BY on the subquery!

**Edit 2:** Updated query and SQL fiddle based on updated question.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have clarified it.. The value of top 3, comes from a diferent column and cannot be fixed as 3

Comment: OK, what column? I'm struggling to understand the details of your question, it's really not clear. You mention records that are "not null" (but there are no nulls in your examples anyway), and "corresponding to an `Id`" but all your IDs are the same...

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I hope this is now correct!

Comment: Great, it sounds like you're basically set then. As for the SSRS parameters, I guess you could do something horrible like pass as varchar then convert to int - e.g. `@intval = convert(int, @varcharval)`. I'm sure there's correct way to pass ints to SSRS though, so it might be a good idea to ask this as new question. If my answer works for you please consider accepting it as the correct one, thanks.

Comment: Thanks BeerCool. This one worked but ended up with a different problem.posted an extension of this problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130369/creating-pivots-based-for-a-rowcount-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

With SQL and such these queries, understanding the problem and imagination of an algorithm or method for solving the problem is too much important, on base of what you want:

> I need to get only last 3 records for targets on the basis of latest 3
>   values for actual

you need to have tow steps:

1.determine the last 3 years of actual values:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [Year]
FROM Your_Table
WHERE Typeofvalue = 1 
ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

2.count the records of target values which their years are in above query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Your_Table
WHERE
  Typeofvalue = 2
  AND 
  [Year] IN (
          SELECT TOP 3 [Year]
          FROM Your_Table
          WHERE Typeofvalue = 1 
          ORDER BY [Year] DESC)
```

---

You can do it with join too instead of subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Your_Table t
JOIN
(
  SELECT TOP 3 [Year]
  FROM Your_Table
  WHERE Typeofvalue = 1 
  ORDER BY [Year] DESC
)q
ON T.[Year]=q.[Year]
WHERE t.Typeofvalue=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the last three actual items and join in the corresponding target items, then count the non-null values:

```
select
  count(Id)
from (
  select top 3
    t2.Id
  from
    TheTable t1
    left join TheTable t2 on t2.Year = t1.Year and t2.TypeofValue = 2
  where
    t1.TypeofValue = 1
  order by
    t1.Year desc
) x
```