# Creating Pivots based for a rowcount in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables T1 and T2.

T1 has the following columns:

```
Id, EntityId, TypeofValue, Year, value
```

`EntityId` can have 7 values:

1,2,3,4,5,100,101

`Typeofvalue` can have 2 values

- 1 indicates Actual
- 2 indicates Target

T2 has the following columns:

```
NoOfRecordsToDisplay
```

I need to fetch the number of records (if existing) for Target corresponding to an Id. The record count (1 if any record is present 0 if none) for Target needs to be grouped into two categories: First having Entityid 1 and Maximum records under Second group with entityids 2,3,4,100,101 [Not 5]

However, the catches are:

- Sometimes Target value might not be present for a year
- I need to get only last records for targets on the basis of NoOfRecordsToDisplay (The number of records to display comes from T2) for actual

Example1:

```
NoOfRecordsToDisplay =3, ID =123
```

The data below should return

```
CountGroup1: 1, Countgroup2: 1
```

as Entityid 1 has least one value for target for last 3 years -2015, 2014,2013 in this case

as Entityid 2 or 3 has at least 1 value for  years -2015, 2014

```
Id  EntityId  TypeofValue   Year    Value
123     1       1           2015    55
123     1       1           2014    56
123     1       1           2013    57
123     1       1           2012    58
123     1       2           2015    50
123     1       2           2014    50
123     1       2           2013    50
123     1       2           2012    50
123     2       1           2015    55
123     2       1           2014    56
123     3       1           2015    57
123     3       1           2014    58
123     2       2           2015    55
123     2       2           2014    56
123     3       2           2015    57
124     1       1           2015    55
124     1       1           2014    56
124     2       1           2013    57
124     2       1           2012    58
124     1       2           2015    50
124     1       2           2014    50
124     2       2           2013    50
124     2       2           2012    50
```

Another dataset

```
NoOfRecordsToDisplay =3, ID =123
```

The data below should return:

```
CountGroup1: 0, Countgroup2: 1
```

as Entityid 1 has no target value for last 3 years (entityid 1 has a target value but for 2012)

as Entityid 2 has at one value for  target years -2015 (entityid 3 has a target value but for 2010)

```
Id  EntityId  TypeofValue   Year    Value
123     1       1           2015    55
123     1       1           2014    56
123     1       1           2013    57
123     1       1           2012    58
123     1       2           2012    58
123     2       1           2015    55
123     2       1           2014    56
123     2       2           2015    55
123     2       2           2011    56
123     3       2           2010    57
```

Thank you so much for your help.

I have been trying to find this solution for a long time, I am not sure if Pivot will help

The question is different from the other one that I had posted as I am trying to create a group count based on entity groups.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question formatting a bit. Can you explain in more detail, step by step, how you arrive at `CountGroup1: 1` in your first example? This sentence "Entityid 1 has 3 at least one value" makes no sense to me

Comment: This seems like almost the same as your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107626/, except even harder to understand. Good luck, @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Please don't double post. I've just gone and formatted your question.

Comment: The question is different from the other one that I had posted as I am trying to create a group count based on entity groups. The reason why I created this post was because it was making the other post complicated. I have deleted that post now.

Comment: You just deleted a question which someone had tried to answer, and you have not responded to requests for clarification in this question so I guess this question is also going to become neglected and also be deleted.